# creación de base de datos en sql server con c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

No me deja crear la Base de datos me arrosa error en "("

```
 public void CreateDatabase(string nombrebd, string diremdf, string direldf, string tamaño, string tamañoldf) 
    {

        string str;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server,1433; User ID = sa; Password =password; ");
        str = "CREATE DATABASE " + nombrebd + "(NAME = " + nombrebd +"_Data, FILENAME = '"+ diremdf+".mdf',SIZE = "+ tamaño +",FILEGROWTH =10%) LOG ON (NAME = "+nombrebd+"_Log, FILENAME = '"+direldf+"Log.ldf', SIZE = "+tamañoldf+", FILEGROWTH = 10%)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: ¿Te arroja algún error, cuál?

Comment: si estas creando la db cuando defines el connection string a que db te estas conectando ? Estas seguro que puedes realizar el open del conexion correctamente

Comment: Porque no utilizar entity?

Comment: hola Leonel bienvenido, revisan tu variable `conexion` y a que BD hace referencia. también que error genera nos puede ayudar a buscar una solución idónea.

Comment: me arroja error en "(" nose que esta mal

Comment: que error te arroja?